# QWidget setGeometry show without use of a QLayout

Tags: qt, user-interface, qwidget

The target is to paint a QWidget subclass in a other QWidget. By give only the coords.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QLabel>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget* w = new QWidget;
    w->show();
    QLabel* l = new QLabel;
    l->setText("Hello World!");
    l->setParent(w);
    l->setGeometry(0,0,100,100);

    return a.exec();
}
```

Why i see nothing on the window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must call [`QWidget::show`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#show) to show the label since you add it *after* the parent widget has already been shown.

```
QLabel* l = new QLabel;
l->setText("Hello World!");
l->setParent(w);
l->setGeometry(0,0,100,100);
l->show();
```

An alternative solution is to show the parent after all the child widgets are already added. You don't need to allocate anything explicitly the heap:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget w;
    QLabel l("Hello World!", &w);
    l.setGeometry(0,0,100,100);
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```